# @RolesAllowed is not working with custom SecurityContext in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a simple jersey 2.4 resource:

```
@RolesAllowed("admin")
public List<Folder> list(){}
```

I also have a ContainerRequestFilter which sets custom securitycontext:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
requestContext.setSecurityContext(new MySecurityContext(...));
}
```

In the list() function i do get the correct securitycontext: MySecurityContext. And a call "securityContext.isUserInRole("admin")" works.

But the annotation @RolesAllowed doesn't seem to do anything, the function isUserInRole of MySecurityContext is never called.

Do i need to do something special to get the @RolesAllowed to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it :-)

@RolesAllowed("admin") not @RolesAllowed("{admin}")

and the most important one:

register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);

Comment: Thank you! I missed adding the *RolesAllowedDynamicFeature* when migrating from Jersey 1.x to 2.x and many hours have been spent looking for exactly this. For anyone wondering where the `register()` call goes, it's in your `javax.ws.rs.Application` implementation that is handed to the ServletContainer (e.g. `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer`) through the usage of `<init-param>` inside `web.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below in your web.xml

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: For anyone coming here from google: this does the trick in Websphere Liberty!